# Normal Approximation in testing for association in a 2x2 contingency table

Tags: central-limit-theorem, contingency-tables

Suppose we have a 2x2 contingency table with binary RVs $X, Y$ and we want to test for independence.
Let $n$ be the total amount of measurements.
Let $n_{11}$ be the number of occurrences of both $X = Y = 1$.
Let $n_{+1}$ and $n_{1+}$ be the number of occurrences of $Y=1$ and $X=1$ respectively.
Let $p_{11} = P(X=1, Y=1), p_{1+} = P(X=1), p_{+1}=P(Y=1)$.

Now, $H_0: p_{11} - p_{1+}p_{+1} = 0$ is the null hypothesis.
Let $\hat{p}_{11} - \hat{p}_{1+}\hat{p}_{+1} = \frac{n_{11}}{n} - \frac{n_{1+}}{n}\frac{n_{+1}}{n}$ be our test statistic.
Now, we have that our test statistic approaches the Normal distribution asymptotically assuming column and row independence, i.e.
$\hat{p}_{11} - \hat{p}_{1+}\hat{p}_{+1} \sim_a N\bigg(0, \frac{1}{n}\big[p_{1+}p_{+1}(1-p_{+1})(1-p_{1+})\big]\bigg)$.

This is what I'm struggling to see. I assume that the CLT is being invoked somewhere, but I'm struggling with the calculation. I have the following:

$\frac{n_{11}}{n} - \frac{n_{1+}}{n}\frac{n_{+1}}{n} = \frac{1}{n}\big[\sum_i X_i Y_i - \frac{\sum_i X_i \sum_i Y_i}{n}  \big] = \frac{1}{n}\big[\sum_i \big(X_i Y_i - \frac{\sum_i X_i \sum_i Y_i}{n^2}\big)  \big]$.
This has expectation zero assuming $H_0$, but I don't know how to get the variance term.
I'm not sure if this is the line of thinking that will get me the result though. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with the variance of a Bernoulli/binomial distribution (e.g. [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Variance_of_Binomial_Distribution))?

Comment: Why do you not use the chisquare test for contingency tables?

Comment: This z-test and the Chi-Square happen to be equivalent. If we let Z be equal to the above statistic, then $\frac{n}{n-1} Z^2$ is the chi square statistic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that I figured it out. We can calculate $\frac{1}{n^2}Var\big( \sum X_i Y_i - \frac{\sum X_i \sum Y_i}{n} \big) $ by brute force, i.e. $\mathbf{E}\bigg[ \bigg(\sum X_i Y_i - \frac{\sum X_i \sum Y_i}{n} \bigg) ^2 \bigg]$. I ended up getting $\frac{p_{1+}p_{+1}q_{1+}q_{+1}}{n} - \frac{p_{1+}p_{+1}q_{1+}q_{+1}}{n^2}$.
As $n \rightarrow \infty$ the first term dominates, which is our desired variance.